# Update h2 on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

So for a few reasons, I need to add item color and item size to product name when user chooses the color and size he wants. However, I've only managed to update the h2 when user has selected both of the selections, and I need the header to update every time the selection is changed.

*HTML:*

```
<h2 class="item_name" style="float:left;">Quartz-kalvot</h2>

<br><br><strong>V&auml;ri</strong><br />
    <select class="item_Color">
    <option value="Ei valintaa">Valitse väri</option>
    <option value="Violet">Violet</option>
    <!-- ... -->
</select>
<br />
<strong>Koko</strong><br />
    <select class="item_size">
    <option value="Ei valintaa">Valitse koko</option>
    <option data-price="20.00&euro;">25cm x 30cm</option>
    <option data-price="30.00&euro;">50cm x 30cm</option>
    <option data-price="45.00&euro;">100cm x 50cm</option>
</select>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
$(".item_size, item_Color").change(function() {
    var vari = $(".item_Color").val();
    var koko = $(".item_size").val();
    $('.item_name').html("Quartz-kalvot (" + vari + ")(" + koko + ")");
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WVCzY/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `.` for the class selector here;

```
$(".item_size, item_Color")...
```

so the event will not bind, to fix;

```
$(".item_size, .item_Color")...
```

Comment: oh... I wonder how it's even possible to forgot that... Stupid me.

Comment: @chr - sometimes it can be the font you use to view code. Take a look at some fonts designed for code.

Comment: @Lix I mainly use Dreamweaver when I'm coding something from scratch and Notepad++ attached to WinSCP when I'm just making modifications to code. Is it possible to change the font for notepad++?

Comment: [This should help you](http://superuser.com/questions/16831/how-can-the-font-size-be-changed-in-notepad). I'm pretty sure you can change the font in any IDE...

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/WVCzY/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".item_size, .item_Color").change(function () {
     var vari = $(".item_Color").val();
     var koko = $(".item_size").val();
      $('.item_name').html("Quartz-kalvot ("+vari+")("+koko+")");
     });

});​
```

You were simply missing a `.` before the first `.item_Color`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add . before `item_Color`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //*************. here
    $(".item_size, .item_Color").change(function () {
     var vari = $(".item_Color").val();
     var koko = $(".item_size").val();
      $('.item_name').html("Quartz-kalvot ("+vari+")("+koko+")");
     });

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the H2 update a function, and call it in the change event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".item_size").change(function () {
        updateH2();
     });

    $(".item_Color").change(function() {
     updateH2();   
    });

});

function updateH2() {
     var vari = $(".item_Color").val();
     var koko = $(".item_size").val();
      $('.item_name').html("Quartz-kalvot ("+vari+")("+koko+")");
}
```

Comment: Yes. But this can easily be reduced to one handler for both selectors. If they are both doing exactly the same action there is no need for redundant calls.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the dot to the `item_Color`

It should look like this

```
  $(".item_size, .item_Color").change(function () {
```